# RecyclerView not hiding certain items

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview

I have an api which has a field called "show_in_list" which is set to true or false. In my adapter for my recycler view I have done this

```
public class EmoticonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EmoticonAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private EmoticonResponse mEmoticon;
private Emoticons mEmoticons;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView mEmoticonButton;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        mEmoticonButton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.emoticonImages);
    }
}

public EmoticonAdapter(Context context, EmoticonResponse response) {
    mContext = context;
    mEmoticon = response;

    if (mEmoticon == null) {
        mEmoticon = new EmoticonResponse();
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;

    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.grid_item_emoticon, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    mEmoticons = mEmoticon.getItem(position);

    if (mEmoticons.getEmoticon().getUrl() != null) {
        if (mEmoticons.getEmoticon().getShow_in_list().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(mEmoticons.getEmoticon().getUrl())
                    .into(holder.mEmoticonButton);

            holder.mEmoticonButton.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            holder.mEmoticonButton.setClickable(true);
        }

    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mEmoticon.getItems().size();
}

}
```

and my XML looks like this for the item in the RecyclerView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/emoticonImages"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

The issue I'm having is that when I load the view there are certain items that aren't visible but are causing large gaps in between the other items and you can still click on them.

[image]

What is it that I'm doing wrong? I'm doing everything textbook but I must be missing something right?

**EDIT** Whole class has been added

Comment: You're setting the visibility of the button to gone but the holder is visible. You need to aim at getting `onBindViewHolder()` to not be called for items you want to not show.

Comment: @howdoidothis how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Post your whole class so I can offer better help. What you need to do, is to filter the dataset so that it only contains visible items, so that when the `.getItemCount()` is called, it returns the number of visible items. So the view is created with only the visible amount of holders

Comment: Another suggestion I have, not 100% sure about this, is that you can perhaps move your isVisible? logic to the `onCreateViewHolder()` so that it returns null if the holder shouldnt be visible. Again, not 100% sure if this will work. but it's prolly easy to give a shot

Comment: @howdoidothis whole class is added :)

Comment: and i updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the adapters constructor, parse the whole emoticon data set and only add those who should be visible to `mEmoticons`. So that `getItemCount()` returns the number of items that you want to be visible, so only that many holders are created.

Your naming is pretty confusing so I had to guess a few things, fix those and try this code:

```
List<Emoticon> filteredEmoticons; // change the class here to what it is in your project

public EmoticonAdapter(Context context, EmoticonResponse response) {
    mContext = context;
    mEmoticon = response;

    if (mEmoticon == null) {
        mEmoticon = new EmoticonResponse();
    }

    filteredEmoticons = new ArrayList<Emoticon>():

    for (Emoticon emoticon : mEmoticon.getItems()) {
        if (emoticon.getUrl() != null) {
            if (emoticon.getShow_in_list().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                filteredEmoticons.add(emoticon);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filteredEmoticons.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mEmoticonButton.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    holder.mEmoticonButton.setClickable(true);
}
```

Comment: Exactly how i were just going to suggest.

Comment: :) confirmation is always reassuring, ty

Comment: @BilalMH Also, if you do it this way you probably dont even need to make the button visible + clickable dynamically, you can just do those in the .xml

Comment: Np, i also hope you understood why / how it works :)

Comment: @howdoidothis yep yep. It makes perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

Here you only hide the `ImageView` but the view will always exist and take some space.
One better solution is to filter your items before. I don't know how and when you set `mEmoticon`, but if you remove the useless item of it, it will work great.

Take care that `getItemCount()` return the good size without your useless item.

Comment: mEmoticon is just declared as a global variable. I don't use it as anything else. I don't really know how to do what you said

Comment: Can you post your entire class?

Comment: added please see above :)